# Do the properties of the euclidean norm hold for hyperreals?

Tags: number-theory

I just want to confirm that triangle inequality still holds if I replace the square root function, with it's hyperreal equivalent in the following function: $\rho(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {(x_n-y_n)^2}}$

Obviously $\forall x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$, $\rho(x,z) \le \rho(x,y) + \rho(y,z)$ is a first order statement, so transfer property should hold, but do I need to watch out for anything in the function itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An, IMO, more convenient formulation of nonstandard analysis is to take a nonstandard model of analysis, rather than simply a nonstandard model of the reals.

The standard model is given by

$$ \mathcal{S} = \mathbf{N} \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{N}) \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{N})) \cup \ldots $$

and is called a "superstructure". The corresponding theory has every element of $\mathcal{S}$ as a constant symbol, and $\in$ as a binary relation symbol. And the axioms of the theory consist of every statement in this language that is true of $\mathcal{S}$.

Since the (graph of the) square root function is one of the constant symbols in the theory, we can see that your statement is a first-order statement in this language. So it holds in nonstandard models too.

---

But if you don't like doing things this way, you could construct the square root function in the usual way: it is defined for $x \geq 0$ and $\sqrt{x}$ is the unique value $y$ with the property that $y^2 = x$. This definition is first-order in the language of arithmetic.

Comment: This isn't for nonstandard analysis. It's for a pet project of mine. This answer should work.